# How to design a database for an Internationale website?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Consider an Internationale website. Let's say this website got some articles. Articles got some common parts between every localized website.

Like for example: ArticleID, Data, Author, CategoryID

+a field (or more) that contains the localized text for this article.

How would you design this table? 2 tables: the first containing the shared article "meta data" (look up) and the other containing a record for every localized version? Like this:

```
   LocalizedID     text           language    ArticleID
      1            "text in EN"    "en"          1
      2            "text in FR"    "fr"          1
```

or a big table containign metadata + localized text? like this:

```
     ArticleID - Data - Author - CategoryID - LocalizedID - TextEN - TextFR - etc
```

(consider the database is not huge, less than 50.000 articles)

thanks everyone

Comment: you could look at how it's done in wikipedia. Free download here: http://www.mediawiki.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go for the first option.. if you ever want to expand (more languages or something) it is easier...

Comment: I am not an expert on fulltext-search, but how would that be a problem?